# Array Traverse from next to Max value

Tags: java, arrays

I am working on a simple game with N players. Suppose N=5 then, players will be:

> Player 1, Player 2, Player 3, Player 4, Player 5.

As in game, one out of five will be the winner. Here is the winning logic.
Each player can have score any one value from following Array i.e. Random value from array.

**0, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16**

Player with highest score will be the winner.

For sample case, I have generated random index between 0 to size of score array (6) and assigned to each player .

```
    int[] data = {0,1,2,4,8,16};
    int[] samples = new int[5];

    Random random = new Random();
    for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
        int value = random.nextInt(6);
        samples[j] = data[value];
    }
```

Then, I've got result like this:

**0 16 2 8 1**

In case of multiple highest scores, first with highest score will be a winner.
In the above case, Player 2 is winner with score of 16.

This is the first round.

Now, I want to assign randomly generated five scores from next to Player 2 i.e. Player 3

Here is the second sample of scores.

**4 1 2 0 16**

What I want is assigning these scores like:

```
Player3 = 4
Player4 = 1
Player5 = 2
Player1 = 0
Player2 = 16
```

Above case is for second round. How to achieve this ?
How to iterate array like this so that I can find winners for 10 round.

Any suggestion, help is appreciated.

Comment: Is player an object with defined parameters?

Comment: Here, Just simple array of size 5. Index define player and value define score

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as this is just practice and not homework here is something that works:

```
  int[] data = {0,1,2,4,8,16};
  int[] samples = new int[5];

  Random random = new Random();
  int value;
  int round = 3; // take in the number of rounds.
  int[] wins = {0,0,0,0,0}; // we'll use this to store the player # of wins.
  // Run the game for the specified number of rounds.
  for(int i = 0; i < round; i++){
    // Get 5 random numbers for each player.
    for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
        value = random.nextInt(6);
        samples[j] = data[value];
    }
    // Set the current winner to junk values.
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int winner = 0;
    // Run though the samples for the current round.
    for(int j = 0; j < samples.length; j++){
      // Print test of each players number.
      System.out.println("Player" + (j + 1) + " Score " + samples[j]);
      // Check in order which player won the round.
        if(samples[j] > max){
          max = samples[j];
          winner = j;
        }
    }
    // Increment the number of wins for the winner.
    wins[winner]++;
    System.out.println();
  }
  // Print test of round wins.
  for(int i = 0; i < wins.length; i++){
    System.out.println("Player" + (i+1) + " Wins " + wins[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm just trying to find out logic behind the problem and I have found here. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help some.  To iterate through all the elements of `samples` starting at some index `start`:

```
  for (int j = 0; j < samples.length; j++) {
      int si = (start + j) % samples.length;
      System.out.println("Loop count: " + j + " looking at samples[" + si + "]");
  }
```